# Using =IMPORTXML with google docs to retrieve last eBay sold item

Tags: google-sheets

Given a URL for a completed item on eBay with 1 or more sales I would like to use =IMPORTXML to retrieve the date of the sale. (*bonus points would be retrieving the last 3 sale dates)

The problems I've ran into are the lack of class on the element, and I don't think google sheets support xpath 2.0.

Here is an example page
http://offer.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&item=182401048832&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2564

any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath `td[5]`

```
=IMPORTXML("http://offer.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&item=182401048832&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2564","//td[5]")
```

[image]